# Randomly getting segfault with char pointer and realloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

This is the piece of code that is getting me headaches:

```
char *input, ch;
int str_size = 0;
input = malloc(sizeof(char));
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (ch >= 32 || ch == '\n') {
        if (ch == '\n')
            line_count++;
        input[str_size++] = ch;
        input = realloc(input, sizeof(char) * (str_size + 1));
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
} 
input[str_size] = '\0';
```

I'm doing a JSON parser in C and my input is:

```
{"":{"":2}}
{"":    [,,,,,2, null, true]}
{"a":+}
```

The problem is that my code randomly gets a segfault problem always on the end of the second line, and sometimes it runs the entire program perfectly:

```
Sergios-MacBook-Pro-2:Trab3-Parser Sergio$ ./parser < casos/1.in
{"":{"":2}}
{"":    [,,,,,2, null, true]}
Segmentation fault: 11
Sergios-MacBook-Pro-2:Trab3-Parser Sergio$ ./parser < casos/1.in
{"":{"":2}}
{"":    [,,,,,2, null, true]}
Segmentation fault: 11
Sergios-MacBook-Pro-2:Trab3-Parser Sergio$ ./parser < casos/1.in
{"":{"":2}}
{"":    [,,,,,2, null, true]}
Segmentation fault: 11
Sergios-MacBook-Pro-2:Trab3-Parser Sergio$ ./parser < casos/1.in
{"":{"":2}}
{"":    [,,,,,2, null, true]}
Segmentation fault: 11
Sergios-MacBook-Pro-2:Trab3-Parser Sergio$ ./parser < casos/1.in
{"":{"":2}}
{"":    [,,,,,2, null, true]}
{"a":+}Error line 3
Number of Objects: 3
Number of Arrays: 1
Number of Pairs: 3
Number of Strings: 4
Number of Numbers: 2
Number of Trues: 1
Number of Falses: 0
Number of Nulls: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
Ps: yes, I'm freeing the input at the end of the code.

@edit: [Link to download the input](https://mega.nz/#!DdFhyYTJ!-EjWizxAYUPiakeDgrKJCJKiMEb3blrqLD4lazO92G4)

This is the result after running valgrind:

```
Sergios-MacBook-Pro-2:Trab3-Parser Sergio$ valgrind ./parser < casos/1.in
==20350== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20350== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20350== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20350== Command: ./parser
==20350==
==20350== Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s)
==20350==    at 0x1003AA34A: mach_msg_trap (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==20350==    by 0x1003A9796: mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==20350==    by 0x1003A3485: task_set_special_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==20350==    by 0x10053F10E: _os_trace_create_debug_control_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==20350==    by 0x10053F458: _libtrace_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==20350==    by 0x1000A89DF: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==20350==    by 0x10001AA1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20350==    by 0x10001AC1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20350==    by 0x1000164A9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20350==    by 0x100016440: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20350==    by 0x100015523: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20350==    by 0x1000155B8: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==20350==  Address 0x10488dd6c is on thread 1's stack
==20350==  in frame #2, created by task_set_special_port (???:)
==20350==

==20350== Invalid read of size 1
==20350==    at 0x100001C6A: main (main.c:141)
==20350==  Address 0x100b5bf8f is 1 bytes before a block of size 50 alloc'd
==20350==    at 0x10009AFC4: realloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==20350==    by 0x1000014A8: main (main.c:21)
==20350==
==20350== Invalid read of size 1
==20350==    at 0x100001FFE: main (main.c:178)
==20350==  Address 0x100b5bfc2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 50 alloc'd
==20350==    at 0x10009AFC4: realloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==20350==    by 0x1000014A8: main (main.c:21)
==20350==
==20350== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20350==    at 0x100002005: main (main.c:178)
==20350==
==20350==
==20350== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==20350==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x100F51000
==20350==    at 0x100001FFE: main (main.c:178)
==20350==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==20350==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==20350==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==20350==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==20350==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==20350==
==20350== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20350==     in use at exit: 26,407 bytes in 165 blocks
==20350==   total heap usage: 230 allocs, 65 frees, 33,776 bytes allocated
==20350==
==20350== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20350==    definitely lost: 408 bytes in 8 blocks
==20350==    indirectly lost: 6,888 bytes in 8 blocks
==20350==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==20350==    still reachable: 4,178 bytes in 3 blocks
==20350==         suppressed: 14,861 bytes in 143 blocks
==20350== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20350==
==20350== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20350== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==20350== ERROR SUMMARY: 4149312 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

[Paste to full valgrind test](https://pastebin.com/XMz2hjbq)

@edit: found reason of memory leaks:
These were the lines 141 and 178 of main.c shown in valgrind, as suggested by @Serge:

141:

```
if (!is_valid_non_string_char(input[i], input[i - 1], input[i + 1])) {
```

178:

```
for (j = 1; input[i + j] != ' '; j++) {}
```

So, I've corrected them by putting the conditions `i - 1 >= 0`, `i + 1 < str_size` and `i + j < str_size`. Now the program runs correctly.

But, what I still do not understand is how the segmentation fault could happen between the lines 13 and 25 of my code (which is the code that I've pasted above), if the problem was at lines 141 and 178, and how this problem was randomly happening with the same input.

@edit: Another point is that, as I've commented, when I had declared the input variable as `char input[600]`, no segmentation fault problems have ever happened.

Comment: Please do not post images when you can cut'n'paste text.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is pointless as it is guaranteed by the standard that it will always be 1. http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html

Comment: @EdHeal removed it

Comment: @Goodies I've only put `sizeof(char)` to say to myself that I've tried everything, including `malloc(1)` haha

Comment: Can't reproduce, [works for me](http://rextester.com/BTZR68013)

Comment: this fragment should work. I wonder if you have other parts of the program which corrupt memory.  run `valgrind` on it.

Comment: It looks to me like you are triggering a failure in the memory management pool by your edge-case use of malloc()/realloc(). This is definitely worth a bug report, but you should also be allocating a larger array, filling it, and then reallocating only once you've reached the end of your current array. This keeps memory pool allocation sane and less likely to artificially exhaust.

Comment: The result of `getchar()` should be stored in an `int`

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the input? It ran smoothly when I was declaring the input variable as `char input[600]`, and now run.codes is having the same problem that I am. I wonder how could it be something wrong with the rest of the code if above the piece that I've pasted there's only declaration of variables.

Comment: Is itt difficult to check if malloc fails? Input == NULL?

Comment: what is at line 141: `==20350== Invalid read of size 1
==20350==    at 0x100001C6A: main (main.c:141)`

Comment: @Serge I've edited my post, please take a look!

Comment: but this is before you allocated the input, isnt it?

Comment: nope, nothing happened before I've allocated the input. The `input[str_size] = '\0';` shown above is at line 25

Comment: Why not remove he `malloc` and `realloc` from the above snippet? Replace `char *input;` to `char input[3000];` )or whatever the size of the file is + a bit) for example. See if the problem still occurs

Comment: @EdHeal, as I've commented, no problems happened when I've declared the variable as `char input[600]`. The point is that no problems should happen when I also allocate the input dynamically. Specially when there's nothing special happening before the memory allocation besides variable declarations.

Comment: You should not `realloc` with `size+1` but with e.g `3*size/2+10` and keep both the allocated size and the used length; and you should **use the debugger** `gdb` and compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: You probably want [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't understand, how will size+1 not keep both allocated size and used lenght?

Comment: realloc can fail. you never check the return value. realloc could move your data - so calling it for each char greatly decrease the performance.

Comment: @SergioToledoPiza i misinterpret the mapping between your fragment and the valgring message. Since your line 178 is not int he fragment and  has an indexed access into 'input' i bet that`[i+j]` is picking something outside the input array. The last valgrind message supports it: `==20350== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20350==    at 0x100002005: main (main.c:178)`. This most likely causes your crash. You need to check your sizes.